# Не работает обратная связь (обратный звонок )

Tags: javascript, java

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://taxigreenline.ru/phone/?name=%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0&phone=43534' from origin 'https://www.taxigreenline.ru' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
taxigreenline.ru/phone/?name=%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0&phone=43534:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
icon-bars.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Ошибки которые выдает .

Вот как написано:

```
</footer>
<div class="popup_bg" id="popup_bg" style=""></div>
<div id="popup" class="popphone order" style="">
         <div class="p_close"></div>
         <div style='background: white; padding: 20px;' class="form form_phone form_popup">
             <div class="title_pop">
                 <h4>Заказать звонок</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="ajax_form" id="clback">
                 <div class="field">
                     <input id='name_name' type="text" name="name" required="">
                     <label  for="phone_phone">Ваше имя</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="field">
                     <input type="tel" id="phone_phone" name="phone" required="">
                     <label  for="phone_phone">Телефон</label>
                 </div>
            </div>
                 <button type="button" id='phone-button' class="submit ">Отправить заявку</button>
                 
             
    <input type="hidden" name="af_action" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script>

$("#phone-button").click(function() {
    phone = document.getElementById('phone_phone').value
    name = document.getElementById('name_name').value
    document.getElementById('phone-button').innerHTML = 'Отправляется...'
    $.get("https://taxigreenline.ru/phone/", {name:name, phone:phone})
        .done(function (data) {
            document.location.href = "https://taxigreenline.ru/yes/";
    
        });
});






$('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').hide("normal");



$('#tel').click(function(){

    $('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').show("normal");
})


$('#ghil').click(function(){

    $('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').show("normal");
})



$('.p_close').click(function(){





    $('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').hide("normal");
})


              </script>
```

Comment: В ошибке написано, используйте написание сайта везде одинаковое или с www или без, taxigreenline.ru и **www**.taxigreenline.ru это два разных сайта. Т.е. адрес сайта у вас `https://www.taxigreenline.ru`  вы с него делаете запрос на совсем другой ресурс `https://taxigreenline.ru`

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке все насписано, чтоб более подробно понять [Прочитайте что такое CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Сайты с www и без www это два разных ресурса, вы делаете запрос сайта с www на другой ресурс (без www) такой запрос блокируется.

Замените строки на

```js
$("#phone-button").click(function() {
    phone = document.getElementById('phone_phone').value
    name = document.getElementById('name_name').value
    document.getElementById('phone-button').innerHTML = 'Отправляется...'
    $.get("https://www.taxigreenline.ru/phone/", {name:name, phone:phone})
        .done(function (data) {
            document.location.href = "https://www.taxigreenline.ru/yes/";
    
        });
});
```

Должно сработать